# Set option val based on array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to build a search that uses multiple drop downs. The script for the search uses the values for the first drop down and the second drop down. It works correct for Acura and MDX, but if I choose RLX it still passes MDX to the search as the value.

I know I have so somehow set for the value for the appended option to be whatever array is chosen in the second drop down, but I have had no luck. I am new to javascript so for all I know there may be a way easier than this to accomplish my goal.

**FORM FOR SUBMIT**

```
            <form name="searchform" onSubmit="return dosearch();">
        Brand:
            <select id="brands">
                <option val="Acura">Acura</option>
                <option val="Chrysler">Chrysler</option>
            </select>

            <select id="item">

            </select>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

**SCRIPT FOR URL STARTING WITH A BASE URL**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function dosearch() {
    var sf=document.searchform;
    var baseUrl = 'http://www.spitzer.com/new-inventory/index.htm?';
    location.href = baseUrl.concat('make='+ sf.brands.options[sf.brands.selectedIndex].value + '&&&&' + 'model=' + sf.item.options[sf.brands.selectedIndex].value + '&&&&' );
return false;
}
```

**SCRIPT FOR DROP DOWNS**

```
// JavaScript Document

$(document).ready(function(){
Acura=new Array("MDX","RLX","ILX","TLX");
Chrysler=new Array('200','3000','Town&Country');

populateSelect();

$(function() {

  $('#brands').change(function(){
    populateSelect();
});

});


function populateSelect(){
cat=$('#brands').val();
$('#item').html('');

   eval(cat).forEach(function(t) { 
        $('#item').append('<option val="">'+t+'</option>');
    });
}



});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setup itself is fine. However, you have a typo:

```
sf.item.options[sf.brands.selectedIndex]
```

Should be:

```
sf.item.options[sf.item.selectedIndex]
```

Or, if you prefer the more aesthetic jQuery:

```
function dosearch() {
    var baseUrl = 'http://www.spitzer.com/new-inventory/index.htm?';
    var brand = $('#brands').find(":selected").text();
    var item = $('#item').find(":selected").text();
    location.href = baseUrl + 'make=' + brand + '&&&&' + 'model=' + item + '&&&&';
    return false;
}
```

Comment: So just so I confirm I understand what your code is doing. The JS I have works fine, but instead you are switching the search script to pull the values from the drop down vs using the array to set values? Which is the simpler way to do things.

Comment: In fact you are pulling the values from the dropdown too with `sf.item.options[sf.item.selectedIndex]`. The jQuery methods is, however, cleaner to use and read.

Answer (score 1):

Wow wow!

Please read some code style for js. If it works it doesnt mean that it's good.

- DO NOT USE eval, EVER! eval = evil
- You forgetting var declaration.
- Inline handler in html bad practice too.
- forEach will break in IE <= 8
- concat is good, plus is good too

... lot of mistakes, that will cost you after.

I`ve wrote you a one liner, but it doesnt have structure. Just some ideas and removed a lot of things.

http://jsfiddle.net/gwEP5/

Whole js code:

```
$(function (){
    // Selector
    var $form = $("#searchform");

    // it could be hashchange in the future
    var setPath = function (url) {
        window.location = url;
    };

    var searchHandler = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // You can serialize whole form just by .serialize
        var url = window.location.pathname + "?" + $form.serialize();
        setPath(url);
    };

    // Handlers, set handlers in js not in DOM, inline delegation is really nasty
    // alias for .submit
    $form.on("submit", searchHandler);


    // Form elements
    var $brands = $('#brands'),
        $item = $("#item");

    // Items list, dont use new Array or String. It`s good way in  
    var items = {
        "Acura": ["MDX","RLX","ILX","TLX"],
        "Chrysler": ['200','3000','Town&Country']
    };

    // eval is EVIL !!!! don`t use it ever
    var populateItems = function () {
        var elements = "",
            value = $brands.val();

        if (items[value] != null) {
            $.each(items[value], function (i, item) {
                elements += "<option value=\"" + item + "\">" + item + "</option>";
            });
        }

        $item.html(elements);
    }

    // Alias .change
    $brands.on("change", populateItems);     

    // init for start
    populateItems();
});
```

Html form:

```
<form name="searchform" id="searchform">
    Brand:
    <select id="brands" name="make">
        <option value="Acura">Acura</option>
        <option value="Chrysler">Chrysler</option>
    </select>

    <select id="item" name="model">

    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Most of the script I found in other Stack Overflow questions and slowly pieced them together bit by bit to accomplish what I had so far. I will note what terms to use going on though!

Comment: I don't know why everyone has this hate against eval. It's not always bad, you know.

Comment: Upon reading both code samples, this one indeed come across as much cleaner & readable , +1

Comment: Banana, i agree that eval is necessary in some cases, like templates or json encode in older browsers. But it always running in window scope, for example in that case evaling a variable from global scope just to get a link to it. You can get error on empty var, and only way to catch it is try {} exept(). It is very slow and big construction, just only to get a value for select.